# SUM when a value is equal or greater than 3,500 only?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are 3 transactions as below and I want to SUM only transaction numbers that have value equal or greater than 3,500:

```
transaction no.   total
0001              1,000 
0001              2,000 
0001              3,000 
0001              4,000 

0002              2,000 
0002              3,000 

0003              1,000 
0003              1,000 
0003              1,000
```

This is the result I expect:

```
transaction no.   total
0001              10,000 
0002              5,000
```

Of course, the transaction no. 0003 won't show because it's below 3,500.

Comment: Use having after your group by `group by [transaction no.] having sum(total) >= 3500`

Answer (score 4):

Use `group by` with `Having Clause`

```
select transactionNo,sum(total) as totalval
from tablename
group by transactionNo
having sum(total)>3500
```

Answer (score 3):

You just have to use having clause as below :

```
SELECT transactionNo, SUM(total) AS total
FROM myTable
GROUP BY transactionNo
HAVING SUM(total) > 3500
```

Answer (score 1):

> The HAVING clause was added to SQL because the WHERE keyword could not
>   be used with aggregate functions.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
GROUP BY column_name(s)
HAVING condition
ORDER BY column_name(s);


SELECT transactionNo, SUM(total) AS total
FROM table_name
GROUP BY transactionNo
HAVING SUM(total) > 3500
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT     transactionNo,
   runningtotal
FROM   (
       SELECT myTable1.transactionNo,
              myTable1.total,
              SUM(myTable2.total) AS runningtotal
       FROM   myTable myTable1
              INNER JOIN myTable myTable2
                   ON  myTable1.transactionNo = myTable2.transactionNo
       GROUP BY
              myTable1.transactionNo,
              myTable1.total
   )            result
WHERE  runningtotal > 3500
```

or you can using **Window Function** and using **CTE**

```
;WITH ResultTable AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT transactionNo,
             SUM(total) OVER(PARTITION BY transactionNo) AS total
      FROM   myTable
  )

SELECT *
FROM   ResultTable
WHERE  ResultTable.total > 3500
```